# Windows service SQLite database?

Tags: windows, windows-services, sqlite-net

searched in google, but couldn't find anywhere if it's possible to make SQLite database in Windows Service?

I have added as a project reference "sqlite-net". But when I try to make connection I get exception "Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when building project it does not copy sqlite3.dll file. So I just downloaded it and copied in folder by myself.